# Graph of common occurrences in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, graph

I have a pandas dataframe as follows :

```
group, user
1,2
1,3
3,4
3,3
3,2
```

And I would like to build a network of common occurrences, where, if it was in a form a dataframe, it could look like this :

```
  2,3,4
2 1 2 1
3 2 1 1
4 1 1 1
```

However, I have 200,000 groups for 7000 users, so all trying to build a massively sparse matrix like this and counting goes beyond my memory capacities :

```
        user1  user2 user3 ... user 7000
group1
group2
group3
...
group200000
```

I am thinking a graph approach would make more sense both conceptually and to save only the important info, but I can't really see how such a network could be built with e.g. networkx.

Would anyone have input on how to solve this?

Comment: But wait why is the entry 3-> 3 to 1? Also 4->4?

Comment: This is because 3 belongs to the same group as itself, once. Same thing for 4. Basically that's the number of times they appear in a group. It doesn't have to be there though, this number can be anything as it won't be an edge in the final network.

Comment: And why arent 4 and 3 connected? THey are both in group 3

Comment: They are connected, hence 1 in the adjacency matrix.

Comment: Sorry I mean 4 and 2. They are in group 3. The adjacency matrix value is 0

Comment: Oh, good catch my bad, manual error.

Comment: Okay added some workaround to this last detail. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what you want is the [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). One way would be to build a network from the dataframe's columns, and compute the matrix with `to_pandas_adjacency`:

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations, chain
from collections import Counter

L = df.groupby('group').user.agg(list).values.tolist()
# [[2, 3], [4, 3, 2]]
# get all edges from each group 
L2_nested = [list(combinations(l,2)) for l in L]
# flatten the nested list to a lsit
L2 = chain.from_iterable(L2_nested)
# Build a counter -> amount of entries = edge weight
c = Counter(tuple(sorted(t)) for t in L2).items()
# flatten the dictionary to tuples (source, dest, weight)
weighted_edges = [(*edge, weight) for edge, weight in c]
# obtain the adjacency matrix
G.add_weighted_edges_from(weighted_edges)

adj = nx.to_pandas_adjacency(G, dtype=int)

   2  3  4
2  0  2  1
3  2  0  1
4  1  1  0
```

Finally to add the logic of values belonging to the same group etc., we have to think of a workaround, since there cannot be a connection of a node with itself:

```
nodes = list(G.nodes())
adj.values[adj.index.searchsorted(nodes), adj.columns.searchsorted(nodes)] = 1

print(adj)
print(adj)

   2  3  4
2  1  2  1
3  2  1  1
4  1  1  1
```

Comment: That looks a lot like what I want indeed! However in my example, the group number does not matter, and (1, 2) does not represent an edge, but just that user "2" belongs to group "1", then the next entry being (1, 3) means that user "3" also belongs to one, which in a graph would result in one edge between 2 <-> 3 with weight 1 as they both belong to 1 group only.

I suppose what you are saying is that I should have a list of all edges beforehand?

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you so much @yatu, you made my afternoon!